# Frank does not find any targets when running frank setup or frank build

Tags: ios, ruby, ios-ui-automation, frank

I am trying to complete the frank tutorial given here: http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/

However when I reach to 'frank setup' (I have cd into the project directory)

Then I get the error:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/frank-cucumber-1.1.12/lib/frank-cucumber/frankifier.rb:73:in `decide_on_target': Sorry, this project appears to contain no targets. Nothing I can do here. (RuntimeError)

This is weird because when I use 'xcodebuild -list' it correctly shows me the "2012 Olympics" target.

Anyone had the same error and found a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue myself. I wonder is this the result of a recent code commit ?

Comment: @AndyDunn have you been succesful with other versions of frank? If, which versions was it? Then I will try install them. I have tried with version 1.2.0.pre1 and 1.1.8 besides 1.1.12 with no luck.

Comment: I havent. Im just assuming it was recent since I found your post the same day. Ive tried earlier versions of xcodeproj since that has something to do with it, but no luck.

Comment: I have tracked the problem down to xcodeproj from cocoa pods version 0.10.1: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj
When I call 'xcodeproj show' from the command line and in the project folder. Then in the returned output no targets is found. I believe it is not a Frank issue then, but an issue in it dependencies. Now I will try to find an older version of xcodeproj and see if it helps.

Comment: @AndyDunn I made it work. After having tracked the problem down to xcodeproj I tried another version of it, and it worked :)
So just uninstall the version of xcodeproj you have probably 0.10.1 with:
sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj --version 0.10.1
And after that install an older version of xcodeproj. I installed xcodeproj 0.9.0 with:
sudo gem install --version 0.9.0 xcodeproj
That should make it work for you also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work. After having tracked the problem down to xcodeproj (0.10.1) I tried another version of xcodeproj (0.9.0), and it worked :)
So just uninstall xcodeproj (0.10.1) with:

```
sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj --version 0.10.1
```

And after that install xcodeproj (0.9.0) with:

```
sudo gem install --version 0.9.0 xcodeproj
```

That's it :)

Comment: Thats totally it, working fine now :) .. I almost had it then, I guess I didn't install the old version of the xcodeproj gem before installing a new one. Thanks for that.